# How to lazy load Firebase data using ionic infinite scroll

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, firebase, infinite-scroll, snapshot

I have a set of data within a users profile which holds the UID of all the posts they have liked. I am using a data snapshot to show these images within the users profile, but I would like to load it lazy or use ionic infinite scroll to load more items as the user scrolls.

I tried by making two duplicate snap shots. First one intialises the feed upon the page loading, and then I wanted the second one to load by using ionic infinite scroller.

But it doesn't work.

Does anyone know of a better way to do this?

### service.js

```
  getWardrobeFeed: function(){
      var defered = $q.defer();
      var user = User.getLoggedInUser();
      var wardrobeKeyRef = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL + '/userProfile/' + user.uid + '/wardrobe');
      wardrobeKeyRef.orderByKey().limitToLast(2).on('child_added', function (snap) {
        var imageId = snap.key();
        userImageRef.child(imageId).on('value', function (snap) {
          $timeout(function () {
            if (snap.val() === null) {
              delete userWardrobeFeed[imageId];
            } else {
              userWardrobeFeed[imageId] = snap.val();
            }
          });
        });
      });
      wardrobeKeyRef.orderByKey().limitToLast(2).on('child_removed', function (snap) {
        var imageId = snap.key();
        $timeout(function () {
          delete userWardrobeFeed[imageId];
        });
      });
      defered.resolve(userWardrobeFeed);
      return defered.promise;
    },

  getWardrobeItems: function(){
      var defered = $q.defer();
      var user = User.getLoggedInUser();
      var wardrobeKeyRef = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL + '/userProfile/' + user.uid + '/wardrobe');
      wardrobeKeyRef.orderByKey().limitToFirst(2).on('child_added', function (snap) {
        var imageId = snap.key();
        userImageRef.child(imageId).on('value', function (snap) {
          $timeout(function () {
            if (snap.val() === null) {
              delete userWardrobe[imageId];
            } else {
              userWardrobe[imageId] = snap.val();
            }
          });
        });
      });
      wardrobeKeyRef.orderByKey().on('child_removed', function (snap) {
        var imageId = snap.key();
        $timeout(function () {
          delete userWardrobe[imageId];
        });
      });
      defered.resolve(userWardrobe);
      return defered.promise;
    },
```

### controller.js

```
  $scope.userWardrobe = [];

  Service.getWardrobeFeed().then(function(items){
    $scope.userWardrobe = items;
  });

  $scope.loadMore = function() {
    Service.getWardrobeItems().then(function(items){
      $scope.userWardrobe = $scope.userWardrobe.concat(items);
      $scope.$broadcast('scroll.infiniteScrollComplete');
    });
  };
```

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/firebase/firebase-util/blob/master/src/Paginate/README.md

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I am currently using this for a news feed, but I can't figure out how to do this if I am not providing a Firebase Ref. All the id of the images are objects within a users profiles and then calling a reference to them within the images folder. How can I achieve it with the link you provided?

Comment: I still haven't figured this out. @FrankvanPuffelen Do you have any ideas on how I can achieve this. I want to lazy a query on a firebase ref